# Numpy reshape a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, reshape

I'm making an application that uses a function that receives as parameter a set of `I` grayscale images of shape `M x N`.

I have

```
print(train_set.shape)    
print(train_set[0].shape)

>>(50,)
>>(133, 100)
```

I need to reshape this dataset to shape `(I, M, N)`.

I'm trying

```
train_set.reshape(len(train_set),len(train_set[0]),len(train_set[0][0]))
```

but I have the following error

```
>>>ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50 into shape (50,133,100)
```

**So, how can I reshape my dataset to `(I, M, N)` or `(50, 133, 100)` in this case?**

EDIT: 
This is how i build the dataset

```
train_set =[]
lbl_train=[]
for cl_ in range(50):
    for ex_ in range(15):
        cl = str("%02d" % (cl_+1,))
        ex = str("%02d" % (ex_+1,))
        img = Image.open('cropped_faces/'+'s'+str(cl)+'_'+str(ex)+'.jpg').convert('L')
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        lbl_train.append(cl)
        mat = numpy.asarray(img,dtype=numpy.float)
        train_set.append(mat.reshape(len(mat),len(mat[0])))

print(numpy.asarray(train_set).shape)
print(numpy.asarray(train_set[0]).shape)
```

Comment: what do you get when you `print(train_set[0][0].shape)` ?

Comment: Try `np.stack(train_set)`.  It looks like you have an array of arrays (but this information is lacking in the question). Depending on how you build `train_set`, numpy may not know how to automatically combine the individual images into one big array.

Comment: what's the output of type(train_set) and type(train_set[0])?

Comment: @MaxPower `print(train_set[0][0].shape)    >>  (100,)`

Comment: @Allen `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: @kazemakase I edited the question and now has how i builded the `train_set`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think what you've got in train_set is a Numpy array of numpy array objects instead of a multi-dimensional array. This should give you what you need:

```
#the np.r_ function will stack all the elements from train_set as a new array with the shape(len(train_set),len(train_set[0]),len(train_set[0][0]))
train_set = np.r_[train_set.tolist()]
train_set.shape
Out[788]: (50, 133, 100)
```

Comment: i did what you said but the output still is the same `train_set = numpy.r_[train_set.tolist()]
    print (train_set.shape)` >> (50,)

Comment: I discovered the problem, some images in the train_set had different sizes... the first six images (133, 100)
(129, 100)
(149, 100)
(149, 100)
(151, 100)
(149, 100)